# zend framework display image using to field in a row

Tags: database, image, zend-framework, echo

I have added images to a database using there directory path as one field in a row and the file extension as another field in a row.

Table code:

```
CREATE TABLE chinaletting (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    category TEXT NOT NULL,
    title TEXT NOT NULL,
    image BLOB NOT NULL,
    imageext TEXT NOT NULL,
    floorroom TEXT NOT NULL,
    spacesize TEXT NOT NULL,
    available TEXT NOT NULL,
    contactname TEXT NOT NULL,
    contactnumber TEXT NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'noemail@test.com'
);
CREATE INDEX "id" ON "chinaletting" ("id");
```

displaying of table:

```
<dl>
    <?php foreach ($this->entries as $entry): ?>
    <dt><?php echo $this->escape($entry->category) ?></dt>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->title) ?></dd>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->image), $this->escape($entry->imageext)  ?></dd>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->floorroom) ?></dd>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->spacesize) ?></dd>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->available) ?></dd>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->contactname) ?></dd>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->contactnumber) ?></dd>
    <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->email) ?></dd>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</dl>
```

on screen display:

[image]

What want to display really is the picture can anyone help

Comment: use <img> tag to display image.

Comment: Thanks sort my issue now is i want to only display rows that fit in a pacific category in the table do you know how to do this x

Comment: not sure, use `if-else` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<dl>
    <?php foreach ($this->entries as $entry) {
      if($this->escape($entry->category) == 'pacific') { ?>
        <dt><?php echo $this->escape($entry->category) ?></dt>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->title) ?></dd>
        <dd><img src="<?php echo $this->escape($entry->image), $this->escape($entry->imageext)  ?>"></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->floorroom) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->spacesize) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->available) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->contactname) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->contactnumber) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->email) ?></dd>
    <?php }} ?>
</dl>
```

For 2 categories:

```
<dl>
    <?php foreach ($this->entries as $entry) {
      if($this->escape($entry->category) == 'shoes' || $this->escape($entry->category) == 'dress') { ?>
        <dt><?php echo $this->escape($entry->category) ?></dt>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->title) ?></dd>
        <dd><img src="<?php echo $this->escape($entry->image), $this->escape($entry->imageext)  ?>"></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->floorroom) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->spacesize) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->available) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->contactname) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->contactnumber) ?></dd>
        <dd><?php echo $this->escape($entry->email) ?></dd>
    <?php }} ?>
</dl>
```

Comment: Hi ya how would i Edit above to get it to display to categorys form a database.:

Comment: @Zara_tj, not sure I understand, can you give me more details as to what you want to achieve ?

Comment: the following will display all records with category shoes:  if($this->escape($entry->category) == 'shoes'). I want to add to this to show shoes + dresses for example

Comment: @Zara_tj, I added the code for 2 categories.  This is really basic PHP.  You should go through a PHP tutorial and try some things.  Then, people will be more than happy to help you out here.  Here is one that I just found that might help you with the basic programming syntax: http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/PHP/